# How do I say "salmon hand roll"?

Tags: translation, food

Which of the above?

- 鮭 手巻き
- 手巻き 鮭
- 鮭 手巻き寿司

Or how could I say it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend 「サーモン**の**手巻{てま}き」 or 「鮭{さけ}**の**手巻き」.　The 「の」 can be dropped but it would sound a little nicer if you insert it.

If you want a phrase for ordering, 「サーモン**を**手巻き**で**！」 would also be natural.  Yes, you can end that with a 「で」.

(「で」 is an ***extremely*** useful particle at eateries, but I will not get into that here.)

Depending on the sushi shop, the staff might use 「手巻きサーモン」 instead, but everyone will understand the first three I listed.

Comment: Technically, there's an unspoken understanding in most sushi restaurants (at least those for common people) that サーモン means "[salmon trout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_trout)", which is a cheaper substitute of real "salmon". If you'd really like to have "salmon", you should order 鮭（さけ、しゃけ）.